# Regular expression to detect comments in code

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java - regular expression finding comments in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code)

How do I find comments in java code with regular expression?
Like `//` and `/*  */`.

Comment: If you type in an actual title, the system will do a search for you so you don't post needless duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

While it might be solveable with regex, the preferable solution when parsing any kind of structured markup is to use a parser that actually understands the language spoken.

In this case: a Java Source Parser like [javaparser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/) or an [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/)-based custom solution using the [Java grammar](http://www.antlr.org/grammar/1152141644268/Java.g).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public class Test {

    // comment 1

    /*
    comment 2
    // no line comment
    */

    char c = '"'; // comment 3, " is not the start of a string literal!

    String s = "/* no comment */ ... /*";

    String t = "*/ also // not a comment";

    private static String getContentsOf(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            b.append(scan.nextLine()).append("\n");
        }
        return b.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        String anyChar = "[\\s\\S]";
        String singleLineComment = "//[^\r\n]*";
        String multiLineComment = "/\\*" + anyChar + "*?\\*/";
        String stringLiteral = "\"(?:\\\\.|[^\"\r\n\\\\])*\"";
        String charLiteral = "'(?:\\\\.|[^'\r\n\\\\])+'";

        String regex = String.format("(%s)|(%s)|(%s)|(%s)|(%s)",
                singleLineComment, // group 1
                multiLineComment,  // group 2
                stringLiteral,     // group 3
                charLiteral,       // group 4
                anyChar);          // group 5

        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(getContentsOf("Test.java"));

        while(m.find()) {
            String matched = m.group();
            if(m.group(1) != null || m.group(2) != null) {
                System.out.println("matched = " + matched);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which prints:

```
matched = // comment 1
matched = /*
    comment 2
    // no line comment
    */
matched = // group 1
matched = // group 2
matched = // group 3
matched = // group 4
matched = // group 5
```

Or, a perhaps more robust solution would be to use a little parser or parser generator. ANTLR has a nice option to define only a part of a language's grammar and ignore the rest. I demonstrated this in [this previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277130/using-antlr-to-parse-a-log-file). The drawback is that you will need to learn a bit of ANTLR...

Comment: Nice one!  But what about `\u002F* */`?  :P

Comment: @Alan: spoil sport! :) I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader...

Answer (score 0):

See previous question: [Java - regular expression finding comments in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657066/java-regular-expression-finding-comments-in-code), or certain random link from google by relevant query: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html