# Java parser rename variable

Tags: java, parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar

I need to write a parser for Java programming language. I've seen some implementations (JavaCC, SableCC) and i think i can handle it.

The thing is I need to rename the variables. Could I do this using the parser?

If yes, how?

Comment: Many IDE's have such refactor functionality: perhaps that is an option?

Comment: Well, a thing like this i need to do myself, a refactoring.

Comment: But why you don't use an IDE for this? I mean, it's some much hassle to find a decent grammar and generate a parser, or write parser yourself, for something that is easily done with Eclipse, IntelliJ or Netbeans.

Comment: Because i need to implement an obfuscator for Java. For this i need a parser first, then a way to rename the variables throughout the code.

Comment: Then say so in the first place please. My next question is: why don't you use an existing obfuscator? Is this homework, or an assignment of some sort? To be frank, if you're already facing problems at this early stage, I don't recommend writing such a thing yourself. No offense meant.

Comment: None taken. Yes, this is a homework, and it's not started yet. I'm documenting first, but thanks anyway for your support :)

Comment: If I had known this was a homework related question (and contained more background information from the start), I wouldn't have voted to close. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2277130/using-antlr-to-parse-a-log-file) is an SO Q&A that demonstrates how you can create a so-called island grammar with ANTLR that will let you scan the input for (in your case) identifiers only. Beware that when looking for the variable `foo`, you're ignoring things like: `class foo { ...`, `/* foo */` and `s = "foo";`, to name a couple of corner cases.

Comment: Take this snippet of code: `package foo;
public class foo {
    int foo;
    void foo() {
        foo:
        for(int foo = 0;;) {
            /* foo */
            System.out.println("foo=" + foo);
            break foo;
        }
    }
}
` which contains 10 occurrences of `foo`, yet only one of them is an instance variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a parser if all you want to do is rename variables globally.  All you need is an (island) lexer that can pick out identifiers, so that you can replace them.  You can get such a lexer from any parser generator that has a Java grammar by simply ignore the parser part.  That should save you a lot of trouble.

If you try to use a parser for this, that builds an AST, it will be easy to determine the identifiers (there will IDENTIFIER tree nodes) and probably even replacing them by smashing the tree nodes. Your problem will be regenerating legal source text.   Most parser generators don't provide text-to-tree-to-text capabilities.

If you want to rename variables according to *scopes*, you need a parser, and full name and type resolution.  That's way harder than a mere parser; the rules about name lookup in Java 7 are pretty complicated.   Again, there are parser generators out there with Java grammars; but in this case, they won't help you unless you want to implement that name and type resolution.  You'll find that a lot more work than you expect.